# Using bins in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I am working on a data frame which has 4 columns in total, i want to bin each column of that data frame iteratively in 8 equal parts. The bin number should be assigned to the data in a separate column for each column.
The code should work even if any different data frame is provided with different column names.
Here, is the code i tried.

```
for c in df3.columns:
    df3['bucket_' + c] = (df3.max() - df3.min()) // 2 + 1
    buckets = pd.cut(df3['bucket_' + c], 8, labels=False)
```

[sample data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soSZp.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CprqR.png)

The respected bin columns display the bin number assigned to each data point according to the range in which they will (using pd.cut to cut column in 8 equal parts) fall.
Thanks in advance!!

sample data

```
gp1_min gp2 gp3 gp4

17.39   23.19   28.99   44.93

0.74    1.12    3.35    39.78

12.63   13.16   13.68   15.26

72.76   73.92   75.42   94.35

77.09   84.14   74.89   89.87

73.24   75.72   77.28   92.3

78.63   84.35   64.89   89.31

65.59   65.95   66.49   92.43

76.79   83.93   75.89   89.73

57.78   57.78   2.22    71.11

99.9    99.1    100      100

100     100    40.963855    100
```

expected output

```
gp1_min gp2 gp3 gp4 bin_gp1 bin_gp2 bin_gp3 bin_gp4

17.39   23.19   28.99   44.93   2   2   2   3

0.74    1.12    3.35    39.78   1   1   1   3

12.63   13.16   13.68   15.26   1   2   2   2

72.76   73.92   75.42   94.35   5   6   6   7

77.09   84.14   74.89   89.87   6   7   6   7

73.24   75.72   77.28   92.3    6   6   6   7

78.63   84.35   64.89   89.31   6   7   5   7

65.59   65.95   66.49   92.43   5   6   5   7

76.79   83.93   75.89   89.73   6   7   6   7

57.78   57.78   2.22    71.11   4   4   1   6

99.9    99.1    100      100    8   8   8   8

100      100    40.96    100    8   8   3   8
```

Comment: can you give an small example inline or runnable code?

Comment: i have attached, refer to the screen shot of sample data frame and expected output.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text such as code, data, error messages, always post the text directly here on SO. Do you think other people want to type this from a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a couple of functions from numpy, namely `np.linspace` to make the bin boundaries and `np.digitize` to put the dataframe's values into bins:

```
import numpy as np
def binner(df,num_bins):
    for c in df.columns:
        cbins = np.linspace(min(df[c]),max(df[c]),num_bins+1)
        df[c + '_binned'] = np.digitize(df[c],cbins)
    return df
```

Comment: @T Burgis it gives the original data frame without bins

Comment: You are doing `df = binner(df,8)`, yes?